# PHP Upload Image:

Tags: php, file, upload

When i try to upload a image it doesn't work, only says the thing that the image doesn't answer to the parameters. This is my code:

```
<?php
include "config.php";
$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif');
$max_filesize = 1572864;
$upload_path = 'images/points/';
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);
if(addslashes($_POST['upload_image']) && !in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes) && filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize) {
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename) && addslashes($_POST["area"]) && addslashes($_POST["type"]) && addslashes($_POST["lat"])
&& addslashes($_POST["lng"]) && addslashes($_POST["description"]) && addslashes($_POST["weight"]) && addslashes($_POST["size"]) && addslashes($_POST["ht"]) && addslashes($_POST["dr"])) {
$send="insert into bd (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8)values('$_POST[area]','$_POST[type]','$_POST[lat]','$_POST[lng]','$_POST[description]','$_POST[weight]','$_POST[ht]','$_POST[dr]')";
$result=$bd->query($send);
echo "Success.";
} else {
     echo 'There is a problem. Please try again.';
}
}
else{
echo "Doesn't answer to the parameters";
}
?>
```

Comment: ZALGO HE COMES!! my eyes!!! are bleeding!!!

Please try to use better format for readability, thank you

Comment: `<br/>` doesn't apply to php code

Comment: Wow, what a mess that code is...

Comment: You have endless syntax errors in that php code. You should start by looking at the http servers log files to see what errors php throws. Without that you are searching in the dark, you are _guessing_ what the problem might be. That is not a good practice. Start learning how to debug. 1.) syntax highlighting in your editor, 2.) http servers error log file, 3.) use a debugger like `xdebug`.

Comment: That <br />s were because the forum previews me the code all on one line. I don't have any php errors(the server doesn't show me, php error showing is on).

Answer (score 0):

`<br />` tags in PHP have to be within an `echo` statement such as follows: `echo "<br />";`

Plus you can remove the `htmlspecialchars()` functions as they are only useful when looking at **echoing HTML code** to the browser - as you are uploading an image (not html code...) there is no need for any of the variables to be compared with this function in the first place. Even then you would **only use** `htmlspecialchars()` when **writing to** the web-page to be seen by users. (i.e. when you want `<br />` to **be seen by people reading your web-page**.)

When you have fixed these issues, please update your question.

Comment: I've updated the code in the first post and that <br />s were because the forum previews me the code all on one line. I tried  it again but all is the same.

Comment: remove all of the `htmlspecialchars()` functions. These are not required.

Comment: And for that data that is importing into the database?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` is **only** for when trying to echo text including html tags. - If I want to `echo "<br />";` (etc..), then you use `htmlspecialchars()`. In **all** other cases, you never use it as this is not what it is designed for.

Comment: I've removed all htmlspecialchars(), but still i have that problem

Comment: can you echo `$send` to the page? if so can you check the contents of that - if one of the values for the query is empty you may be able to see your problem there.

Comment: The problem is not in the query i am not uploading nothing for the image to the DB.

Comment: Then I don't understand why you have a query if you are not uploading any of the data for the image? It seems completely redundant.

`&& !in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes) && filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)` in this section of your code - surely you want `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] < $max_filesize` otherwise it will only allow files with a **larger** file size than the max specified. Also surely you want the allowed extensions as `in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes)` not `!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes)` as otherwise any allowed file-types will be disallowed...

Comment: Thanks i've done that mistakes because i've copied the code from one lesson and forgoted to edited it, but i have another question. I want to upload the link to image in the database. I want link to be something like that images/points/image_name.png. I've tried that - $image='images/points'.$_POST['upload_image']; but it doesn't work. How to make that link?

Comment: My code now is that, but i still have the same problem:
if(addslashes($_POST['upload_image']) && in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes) && filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) < $max_filesize) {
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename) && addslashes($_POST["area"]) && addslashes($_POST["type"]) && addslashes($_POST["lat"])
&& addslashes($_POST["lng"]) && addslashes($_POST["description"]) && addslashes($_POST["weight"])
&& addslashes($_POST["size"]) && addslashes($_POST["ht"]) && addslashes($_POST["dr"])) {

Comment: Have you even got code to connect to your database, does it include a table called `bd` with field-names exactly as in the query?
By upload link to image in the database, what exactly do you mean? If you are trying to use a database to store image information - the way to get the data out will be to use a `SELECT` statement etc.
The way you are doing this is strange. Why move an uploaded file to a permanent location on your server AND store the image data in the database?  Do one or the other, not both.

Comment: I am trying to move the image to location on the server and upload link to that location in the database. Is there any way to upload image into the database?

Comment: Why do you need the link to the location in the database? Plus if all you want in the database is the link, then there is no need to store ALL of the data regarding the image in the database, you would only need `$upload_path . $filename` stored within a single field in the database.
Comment out the query code for now using `//` before each line of code then try to see if your image is copied across to the permanent folder on your server to begin with while the database related code is disabled.